# tkinter scale with two sliders?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-scale

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a single scale widget with two "sliders" from the `tkinter` module? Or anyway to fake it?

Such as (edited with GIMP):

[image]

I am thinking placing one scale on top of another scale, but with a transparent background?

Comment: I have never seen this been used. Can you give a use case?

Comment: Using it to crop images, movies, sound files,... It is seems to be standard practice in video editing software.

Comment: I don't think this is there in tkinter. You can try implementing it using a Canvas.

Comment: You can file this as a bug in Tk.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: why file a bug? The scale isn't broken, it simply wasn't designed to work this way.

Comment: bug with a wish severity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with the scale widget. You can't give it a transparent background and stack them.

If I had to implement this functionality, I would use a canvas widget and draw my own sliders. 
It's not very hard to do, but obviously it's going to be more work than an off-the-shelf widget.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/MenxLi/tkSliderWidget) is a custom widget using a canvas, made by MenxLi.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work: [Range Slider](https://pypi.org/project/RangeSlider/) Module

You can see how it looks,

[image: My screenshot]